# How to modify a query engine?

Tags: database

I keep hearing "we modified the query engine of some DBMS so that now it can do this or that". What does that actually mean? Is it doable on closed source DBMSs?

Answer (score 0):

Read here for DBMS:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_management_system

No, it's not possible to change the engine of a closed source DBMS.